# Rails error: undefined method `push' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

So I have the following code:

```
new = @params[collection.to_s + '_attributes']
old = @model.send collection

if new.nil?
  old.clear
else
  new_records = new.map { |_, e| e[:id] }
  if !new_records.nil? && !old.nil?
    old.not_in(id: new_records).destroy_all
  end
end
```

The problem is I didn't use 'push' function anywhere in my code and based on the stacktrace the error occurs when executing:

```
old.not_in(id: new_records).destroy_all
```

I'm new to Rails so I hope someone can help me. Thanks in advance!

**UPDATE**

I ended up using delete_all instead of destroy_all for now. I think it was causing the error. It's working now but it would really be nice if I could find out why it wasn't working with destroy_all.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with this piece of code? What is the code for `not_in`?

Comment: I'm not really sure too. Sorry for the incomplete details. I actually thought not_in is a built-in function.

Comment: I don't think `not_in` is rails command, try `old.where.not(id: new_records) .destroy_all`

Comment: If you have a stacktrace, you should add it to the question.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think `not_in` is rails command, Instead, try

**`old.where.not(id: new_records).destroy_all`**

or, `not in` can be used like this.

**`old.where('id NOT IN (?)',new_records).destroy_all`**

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
old.where.not(id: [new_records]).destroy_all
```

Not in always requires array.